# outer doesn't work with mahalanobis in R language

Tags: r, statistics, contour

I would like to draw contour curves in R language.
To do so, I tried to prepare the data with function outer
but it didn't work properly.

Is there anyone who can point out the problem?

```
iris[c(1,51, 101),]
x <- seq(0, 4, length=50)
y <- seq(0, 4, length=50)

seto<-subset(iris[1:50,],select=-Species)
virgi<-subset(iris[101:150,],select=-Species)
seto.m<-apply(seto[1:45,],2,mean)
virgi.m<-apply(virgi[1:45,],2,mean)
seto.v<-var(seto[1:45,])
virgi.v<-var(virgi[1:45,],)

fn <- function(x, y) mahalanobis(c(x, y), seto.m[1:2], seto.v[1:2, 1:2])
fn(3, 4) # works properly

z <- outer(x, y, fn) # doesn't work
```

I got an error saying "Error in x %*% cov : non-conformable arguments"
I think the dimensions of the matrix and vectors are consistent, though ...

I used a function

```
fn <- function(x, y) x^2+y^2
```

and it worked

Answer (score 1):

The function in `outer` must be vectorized.  Use `Vectorize` to convert it to one if it is not.

```
z <- outer(x, y, Vectorize(fn))
```